# Self hosting fonts - not working in IE 9

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am self-hosting fonts that I got from fonts.com. Like in their demo, I inserted @font-face declarations like you see below, added the Fonts folder. It works fine in all browsers but IE. What is the deal with IE? Ideas how to resolve this?

```
@font-face{
font-family:"HelveticaNeueW01-Thin";
src:url("Fonts/56be84de-9d60-4089-8df0-0ea6ec786b84.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/56be84de-9d60-4089-8df0-0ea6ec786b84.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/50d35bbc-dfd4-48f1-af16-cf058f69421d.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/278bef59-6be1-4800-b5ac-1f769ab47430.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/2e309b1b-08b8-477f-bc9e-7067cf0af0b3.svg#2e309b1b-08b8-477f-bc9e-7067cf0af0b3") format("svg");
}
```

UPDATE: I see this error in developer tools in IE:

*CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.*

Comment: What version of IE? And where are you referencing the font on the page? And do you have an `<iframe>` on the page with the font in it?

Comment: IE 9! (edit: not 8). I have an external style sheet which is where I declared @font-face; no iframes, just simple HTML pages.

Comment: Do you have a demo site?

Comment: no, the pages are not accessible from outside of our network.

Comment: Now I see it's some permissions error.

Comment: You will need to make sure the version you are using of the fonts.com webfont is one that allows self-hosting, and that you have the right fonts.com plan to obtain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this works in IE8 & 9

```
src:url("Fonts/c231c05e-5ca6-4992-80fc-58689efdf54f.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/c231c05e-5ca6-4992-80fc-58689efdf54f.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),url("Fon...
```